# change date in a week wise not in day wise

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

Here i use Some label to display the date . And i have 2 arrow button to move back and previous dates.Like below:

```
   (button)  < **27Dec 28Dec 29Dec 30Dec 31Dec 1Jan** >(Button)
```

Here is the code for that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
firstdate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:-5 toDate:[NSDate date] options:nil];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM,yyyy"];
    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate: firstdate];

    [self dateChange];
}
-(void)dateChange
{
    NSArray *labelArray = @[flabel, slabel, tlabel, folabel, fivlabel,sixlabel];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:firstdate options:nil];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)labelArray[i];
        label.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
        if (i==5) {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMM,yyyy";
            dateLabel.text = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate] capitalizedString];

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

            if ([[dateFormat stringFromDate:nextDate] isEqualToString:[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]])
            {
                leftBtn.enabled = false;
                //It's the same day
            }
            else
            {
                leftBtn.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)calRight:(id)sender {

    firstdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:86400 sinceDate:firstdate];
    [self dateChange];


}

- (IBAction)calLeft:(id)sender {
 firstdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-86400 sinceDate:firstdate];
    [self dateChange];
}
```

The above code will work like if i press back button it will go by one by one date change:

```
     < **27Dec 28Dec 29Dec 30Dec 31Dec 1Jan** >
```

Now if i press left arrow:

```
  < **26Dec 27Dec 28Dec 29Dec 30Dec 31Dec** >
```

But what i need if when i press left arrow or right arrow it should by week by week like this:

```
 < **27Dec 28Dec 29Dec 30Dec 31Dec 1Jan** >
```

Now if i press left arrow:

```
  < **21Dec 22Dec 23Dec 24Dec 25Dec 26Dec** >
```

Now if i press left arrow again its should like this:

```
 < **16Dec 16Dec 17Dec 18Dec 19Dec 20Dec** >
```

Please what should i need to change to get like that to change date in week wise.Please help me!

Comment: I have no idea what you are currently doing and you would like to do, too much "when left when right then date then left then date then right". What does the *actually* do? What comes to mind first is changing `NSCalendarUnitDay` to `NSCalendarUnitMonth`

Comment: see actually i used `6 labels` and `2 button` ... that `2button` is like arrow for left and right to change the date. now its changing one by one date.Nut i need like change in week wise.Please see my example above in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the buttons to change `firstDate` by 7 days instead of one, change your button methods to:

```
- (IBAction)calRight:(id)sender {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    firstdate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:7 toDate:firstdate options:nil];
    [self dateChange];
}

- (IBAction)calLeft:(id)sender {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    firstdate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:-7 toDate:firstdate options:nil];
    [self dateChange];
}
```

Note: your current code using `86400` is bad. Never use such code to do date math.

Comment: i am getting error in first line for `calander`  error is =  `use of undeclared identifier 'calander' `